How to calculate gradient of data on non-orthogonal ordered grid?
I have a grid of xy-coordinates that I generate using np.meshgrid. The spacing in x-direction is constant, the y-coordinates are scaled, as a function of x. In this specific case, this results in a cloud of points that lie on a trapezoid, with a side length of 2 on the left and 1 on the right side. I have a function f(x, y), and I want to get the gradient of that function in y-direction and in the direction of each row of points. How can I use np.gradient with xy-arguments to do this? I find the documentation somewhat confusing.
x = np.linspace(0, 1, num=20)
y = np.linspace(-1/2, 1/2, num=10)
x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
y_grid = y_grid * (2 - x_grid)

f = x_grid ** 2 - y_grid ** 3  # example function

gradient = np.gradient(f, x_grid, y_grid)  # something like this?
# with gradient[0] being in the row-direction (in xy-space) and gradient[0] being in y-direction

EDIT: I found one way to do this, as np.gradient can take arguments of coordinate positions, but only as 1D arrays, meaning that the gradient must be calculated for each row and each column independently. For my specific case, where the x-spacing is constant in each row, the gradient can be calculated as follows:
df_dy = np.array([np.gradient(f[:, j], y_grid[:, j], edge_order=2) for j in range(y_grid.shape[1])]).T
df_drow = np.array([np.gradient(f[j], np.linalg.norm([x_grid[j] - x_grid[j, 0], y_grid[j] - y_grid[j, 0]], axis=0), edge_order=2) for j in range(x_grid.shape[0])])

Basically, each row must be treated as a new axis, with the spacing in this axis being calculated using the distance between the points (which I calculate using np.linalg.norm)
Since this uses loops, which I would like to avoid, I will keep the question open for more efficient solutions.

How many times are you computing the gradient in your code? Is it just a one-time thing or many times?

@jared The grid can get quite large (probably around 100x200) and I want to optimize the code as it will be used in an iterative optimization.

What changes between iterations?

@jared The values on the grid. The grid itself remains unchanged, which is why I have now implemented it in a way, so that the grid spacing is saved at some point.

Actually, scratch that. Everything, except probably the dimensions, changes each iteration.
